# how to get sessions for all functions at once in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have created the session in login function. Now I want to use the created session on all other functions too if a user login then the created session should be applied to all other functions.

Thanks

Comment: Thats how sessions work. Have you read the codeigniter user guide on sessions?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)   For getting Good suggestion regarding your question you need to show some of your effort i mean what you have tried so far, what error you get while running a code. A good question get more attention and better solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to understand session first.

**How do Sessions work?**

Sessions will typically run globally with each page load, so the Session class should either be initialized in your controller constructors, or it can be auto-loaded by the system. For the most part the session class will run unattended in the background, so simply initializing the class will cause it to read, create, and update sessions when necessary.

To initialize the Session class manually in your controller constructor, use the $this->load->library() method:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Once loaded, the Sessions library object will be available using:

```
$this->session
```

Session data is simply an array associated with a particular session ID (cookie).

Visit CI Documentation of Session For More detail
See it live here: <kbd>[Session](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In your login section

```
$this->db->where('email',$email);
$this->db->where('password',$pass);
   $query = $this->db->get('admin');
$data= $query->result_array();
if($data){
$this->session->set_userdata('sessionVariable', $data);
redirect('controller_name');
}
```

Open autoload.php from `application/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

OR

load session libraries in `__construct()` of your controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

                $this->load->library('session');

    }
```

To get session data

```
$sessionData   = $this->session->userdata('sessionVariable');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can autoload the sessions in `config.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','Session','email');
```

**OR**

You can create a Base Controller in Core folder and extend all your other controller to that base controller.

Like this

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public $data = array();
    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['errors'] = array();

        $this->data['site_name'] = config_item('site_name');
        $this->load->library('session');



    }
}
```

Now All Your other Controller should be extended to your Base Controller instead of `CI_Controller`

In Your Controller

**Controller 1**:

```
class Login extends MY_Controller
{
  function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();


 }


}
```

**Controller 2:**

```
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller
{
  function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();


 }


}
```

So You will get just need to load your library is your base controller and get all the goodness of base controller in the child controllers. This will give you better `hierarchy`, `code management` and `security`